# Are these opencv functions accelerated by ARM NEON?

Tags: android, opencv, neon

I'm currently using OpenCV on an android based device which supports ARM NEON.The OpenCV version is 2.4.9.

Functions such as cvCanny, cvDilate, cvResize, cvtColor are used, and I want to speed them up.

What i want to know is that if these functions are already written in the form that can be accelerated by the NEON architecture. How can i know the origin code of these functions, and what other functions are accelareted by NEON? Is there any more suggestions on optimization? Thank you!

Comment: I think optimizing these functions for a specific architecture may not be so fruitful, you should try to scale down the image and then apply these functions.

Comment: last time I checked openCV (1+ year ago) it wasn't - at least I found hardly anything NEON optimized in the whole project. I doubt it changed much since then considering openCV being pretty much dead for the industry.

Comment: @plaes Maybe my question is not specified. One of my question is where can i find the source code in the OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk folder. Now I know where it is. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Eu.Dr. Thanks for your advice. I know the scale of the image affects the processing time a lot. I just want to know if there is another choice.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE Thanks for the information, I'll try to check it out myself.

Answer (score 3):

As @plaes suggested take the [source code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/2.4.9/opencv-2.4.9.zip/download) and find out for yourself.

Source code is divided in modules and can be found (unsurprisingly) in the *modules* directory.

To get you started here is where the functions you're looking for are located.

- `cvCanny()`: *imgproc/src/canny.cpp*
- `cvDilate()`: *imgproc/src/morph.cpp*
- `cvResize()`: *imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp*
- `cvtColor()`: *imgproc/src/color.cpp*

Comment: Thanks! This really helps me! I was looking for the source code in the OpenCV_android sdk. That's incorrect.